# What explosive compound would be the most likely first explosive developed by a race?

Tags: organic-chemistry, history-of-chemistry, explosives

Elaboration on title: What would *most likely* be the first explosive compound that some individual would create if they were just mixing together random things they had available? I'm not talking about our world history, where it was the discovery of black powder in China about 1200 years ago. I'm talking about some arbitrary race somewhere in the universe; what would most likely be the first explosive they develop, combining anything organic they could get? Would it be black powder? Nitroglycerin? Nitrocellulose?

(Keep in mind that this question is coming from someone who isn't really a chemistry nerd :p)

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based, actually, so I decided against closing it unilaterally. The community might disagree. I think if you explain why you want this information, (is it for writing some book or something?) then it can probably be left open. You should use the tag chemistry-in-fiction instead of history-of-chemistry as well, since you're not asking about real history.

Comment: Are you serious, or is this info for a book (fiction/fantasy)? If it's the latter, then the choice of compound is really just up to you (the author). If it is the former, you'll have to specify what *kind* of environment this "race" (of what?) live in; throw in a little geochemistry and you may have your answer. Besides... **how would YOU define an "explosive"?**

Comment: @ortho Actually, I think it's better off on the WorldBuilding.SE...no... it is *meant* for the WorldBuilding.SE. So, migrate? O:)

Comment: @paracetamol It might very well do better on worldbuilding, but migration should only occur if it is definitely off-topic on the original site. Simply because it is better for site X does not necessarily make it off-topic for site Y; sometimes it does, but not always.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. The first such compound discovered at some particular hypothetical planet will depend on the geology, geochemistry, ecology, plant biology, and other factors of that hypothetical planet. It could even be some compound not naturally occurring on Earth. There is no single answer here, so this is a poor question for Chem.SE; it is an ideal question for Worldbuilding.SE, though.

Comment: @hBy2Py I disagree. If we allow other geochemistry then you are right, but the question is OK if we interpret it as an alternative history of this planet. In fact it is interesting in that context and potentially offers useful chemical insight.

Comment: @matt_black From the post: "I'm talking about some arbitrary race somewhere in the universe". As written, off-topic.

Comment: I think the question is interesting, yet too broad and opinion based. For example, I could answer with "Definitely black powder," until or unless you remind me that on the planet in question there happens to be little to no sulfur and the atmosphere is comprised entirely of argon. I'd like to see it narrowed-down and will happily vote to reopen when the scope of the question is amended.